# If the prior and likelihood not be conjugate, how to get conditional distribution to sample from using Gibbs sampling?

Tags: bayesian, likelihood, prior, gibbs, conjugate-prior

I know that when prior is conjugate with the posterior, by writing the loglikelihood and log prior and eliminate the non-independent terms for each parameter one can get the conditional distribution for each parameter. But what if these two not be conjugate? how one can get the conditional distribution for each parameter?

Comment: Any method to generate from an unnormalized density should work. For example, forms of accept-reject (including adaptive methods), slice sampling and Metropolis-within-Gibbs steps can each work in suitable situations, With accept-reject, for example, one trick I have used on the odd occasion is to use piece-wise conjugate priors to construct an envelope of a prior, or mixtures of conjugate priors to do the same; at other times, it was easier to work directly on the conditional posterior and construct some envelope (majorizing function) there.

Answer (score 2):

Given a closed-form prior $\pi(\theta_1,\theta_2,\ldots)$ and a closed-form likelihood $\ell(\theta_1,\theta_2,\ldots)$, the conditional densities remain available up to a constant:
$$\pi(\theta_1|\theta_2,\ldots) \propto \pi(\theta_1,\theta_2,\ldots) \times \ell(\theta_1,\theta_2,\ldots)$$
Therefore any simulation method targeting this density can apply (if feasible). An primary instance is [Metropolis-within-Gibbs](http://stat.econ.osaka-u.ac.jp/%7Etanizaki/cv/papers/bayes.pdf), which remains a form of Gibbs sampling (at stationarity).

Comment: Let's suppose that the likelihood is multivariate Gaussian and then the prior is Laplace, can we still use Gibss sampler?

Comment: simulating a density proportional to $\exp\{-a(\eta_1-\theta_1)^2-b|\theta_1|)\}$ (in $\theta_1$) is feasible by accept-reject.

Answer (score 0):

If the prior and likelihood aren't conjugate, you can't easily derive an expression for the conditional distribution, so you can't use Gibbs sampling (you can, as @Xi'an says obtain the density as a function, but that's more complicated!).

The usual solution to this is to use a different sampling algorithm, like Metropolis-Hastings (which is simple enough to implement), or Hamilton Monte Carlo (very fast, used by [Stan](https://mc-stan.org/) and [PyMC3](https://docs.pymc.io/)). The speed and flexibility of HMC is one reason for the popularity of Stan and PyMC3 over JAGS, which primarily uses Gibbs sampling.

Comment: The conditionals are still available as a function.

Comment: @Xi'an can we use Gibbs? do we need exact expression for that?